# confussion in simple present and past tenses regarding helping verbs

Tags: grammar

Why are no helping verbs used in present and past simple tense? I have tried searching on YouTube and Bing but can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Because this is how the language works. I'm not sure if one can answer "why."

Comment: Excuse me but can you give an example of what you mean exactly by saying "no helping verbs are used in Present Simple and Past Simple tenses"?

Comment: He is talking about auxiliary verbs, like "is."

Comment: The simple present has the same form as the infinitive, *sans* "to". The simple past just modifies a *regular* verb by adding "ed".

Comment: I don't understand the problem, either. I _can_ do it. (simple present) I _could_ do it. (simple past) Can it be that OP means _Why are auxiliary verbs solely used in simple tenses?_ (the obligatory switch from _can_ to _be able to_ resp. from _must_ to _have to_)